# Generate hierarchy of employees

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables: `EmployeeMaster` and `EmployeeDetails`. The schema of both are as below:
[image]

Sample data in both tables is shown:

[image]

[image]

I want to generate the hierarchy using `EmployeeDetails` table primarily. This table contains a column named: Manager. The `EmployeeId` of the Manager needs to be picked from the table `EmployeeMaster` table.

This is how the hierarchy needs to be formed. An EmployeeId is passed as a parameter to a stored procedure. The two supervisors of this Employee needs to be picked and 10 employees below this employee in seniority needs to be picked.

For instance, I pass the EmployeeId of Josh.Berkus to the stored procedure. The stored procedure query should return hierarchy as below:

[image]

I want the final output in this format:

Employee_Id ....  Manager_Id

----------- .... ------------

Please note that Manager_Id is the EmployeeId of Manager.

I tried using a CTE with union all query, but not able to get it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you will need to work out the recursivity since on manager can have a manager...
take a look at:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

The thing is that your going to need 2 queries... one to go "up" the hierarchy and one to go down... and then union the results...

why don't you merge the two tables, since one person cant have 2 managers right?!? Specially because a manager is also a employee... this will simplify everything...

Comment: Alternatively, I am thinking to create a single temporary table and fill in records from both tables. In this case, how the query will work?

Comment: @RKh as I said your stored procedure will have to run 2 queries: one to go up and another down and then you can UNION the results... check the new link in my answer...

Comment: I tried CTE but it didn't work correctly. You are right, two queries are needed to fill in a third table. Any idea on how to get 10 employees below the selected employee?

Comment: @RKh the second link in my answer has a step by step on how to solve your exact problem (but using the adventure works database)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CROSS JOIN` to create a link between all your records and then you can put the condition to select only those columns that have a ***manager-employee*** relationship between them.

The code should be something like this:

```
SELECT 
    ed.employeeid 'Employee ID',
    em.employeeid 'Manager ID', 
FROM EMPLOYEEMASTER em CROSS JOIN EMPLOYEEDETAILS ed
WHERE ed.manager = em.username
```

Comment: This I did but I am not able to pick the two superiors above the employee and the ten juniors below.

Comment: Then you would have to join the tables 9 more times in order to get this level of hierarchy.

Comment: @RKh http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ Here is a link you might find useful..

Comment: @Leonardo I agree, but is there any other way? This is the only way I am aware of..

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu check my answer... cross join will generate one million results when the table is only 1000 items long...

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need to implement some recursion here in order to get full hierarchy.

Here is a quick and dirty example of how you can implement this to get manager hierarchy. You would need something similar for lower level hierarchy too

```
create function dbo.GetManagerHierarchy
( 
@EmpID int
)
returns varchar(100)
as
begin
declare @result varchar(100)
declare @managerId int

SET @managerId = (select top 1 Manager from EmployeeDetails where EMployeeId)
if @managerId is not null then
   SET @result = dbo.GetManagerHierarchy(@managerID) + '-' +  CONVERT(varchar(100), @managerId) + 
else 
   SET @result = ''   

return @result 

end
```